# How do you find the directory of a command?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Location of file folders of installed programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54395/location-of-file-folders-of-installed-programs)

For example the following are the same

```
# /usr/bin/php updateDatabase.php

# php updateDatabase.php
```

But how would I infer the location of the php command to be in /usr/bin?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use the `whereis` command to find the location of an executable binary on your system.

Example:

```
$ whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

**EDIT:** From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54395/location-of-file-folders-of-installed-programs/54718#54718) to a similar question, you can also use the `which` command.

Example:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

Comment: This is wrong. `whereis ts-node` only returns 'ts-node:' which isn't the location.

Answer (score 8):

When the program can be run without specifying the full path, then its directory is in your `$PATH` variable.

Run

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/cweiske/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: what a great answer, now I have to look manually in each one of these directories

Comment: @Powereleven No you don't, you can write a script that searches these directories and look for the script.