# 'sudo nping -xxxx' command from script. how to disable the password request from sudo

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, sudo

I am using the `nping` tool to run tests on several networks.
I also wrote some scripts to automate the parameters of such tests.
I also need to avoid `sudo` to ask the password every time a new instance of the terminal is launched (the tool will be included in a custom bootable USB that some colleagues -not linux users- will use for testing remote networks -static LANs)

I plan to include a password disabling line in `/etc/sudoers.d` for the nping command

```
%someUsers ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /<where_the_hell_is_nping?>/nping
```

I cannot find where the nping command is placed though.

I am not an experienced user of Linux myself, so apologies in advance if the question sounds dumb

Comment: Why do you need `sudo` at all to run `nping` ?

Comment: @Soren A: without sudo I get "Couldn't acquire a IPv4 raw socket. Are you root?" returned by nping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `which` command to find where are located command. Here is a little example with `ls` :

```
damadam@Pc:~$ which ls
/bin/ls
damadam@Pc:~$ /bin/ls
Bureau        node_modules       Public        Vidéos      Images               
desktop_session  Modèles       openxenmanager     Shared
Documents    Musique       package-lock.json  Téléchargements
damadam@Pc:~$
```

Refered to : [How do you find the directory of a command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79063/how-do-you-find-the-directory-of-a-command)

Comment: A said: dumb question. thnx though the which command did the trick.